# Cypress command timeout of '8710ms' exceeded

Tags: typescript, cypress

I have a test which is written in cypress and failed. The test execution is successfully completed and passed. But once the execution is completed after 8 seconds, the passed test is turning back to fail for the following reason

> "Cypress command timeout of '8710ms' exceeded."

**Console log**

> Cypress Warning: Cypress detected that you returned a promise in a
>   test, but also invoked one or more cy commands inside of that promise.
>
> The test title was:
>
> Cics Switch Test Suite Default CICS Switch Tenant License Value
>
> While this works in practice, it's often indicative of an
>   anti-pattern. You almost never need to return both a promise and also
>   invoke cy commands.
>
> Cy commands themselves already promise like, and you can likely avoid
>   the use of the separate Promise.

This is my `it` block code

```
it("Default CICS Switch Tenant License Value", async () => {
    loginPage.portalLogin(
      quickregisterPage.userInfo.emailAddress,
      quickregisterPage.userInfo.password
    );
    loginPage.logoDynatrace().should("be.visible");
    trialLicenceDetailsPage
      .getTrialLicenceDetailsPageTitle()
      .should("have.text", "Trial license details");      
  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `cy` commands already handle the promises.

it will work if you remove the `async` command in your `it` block.

Comment: you saved the day for me I had the same issue and was about ask it on Stackoverflow.

Comment: **async** is needed if you have at least one **await** in your test